# JSDom karma angular setup

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, jsdom

I want to be able to use JSDOM as browser for running jasmine tests in angular using karma.

I installed the *jsdom* and *karma-jsdom-launcher* using the following commands:

```
npm install jsdom --save-dev
npm install karma-jsdom-launcher --save-dev
```

Once the packages were installed I added the plugin to karma.conf.js

```
require('karma-jsdom-launcher')
```

However, when I run the test using the command *ng test --browsers=jsdom*, I get

```
10% building 4/4 modules 0 active23 04 2020 13:09:45.095:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser jsdom
23 04 2020 13:09:57.422:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9877/
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined]
```

Below are the versions I am working with

```
Node version - 12
Angular version - 9

"jsdom": "^16.2.2",
"karma": "~4.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"karma-jsdom-launcher": "^8.0.2",
```

Am i missing something? How can I run my test using JSDom and not chrome browser?

Comment: Could you try to configure the browser from the `karma.conf.js`? I mean adding the `config.set({browsers: ['jsdom'],});` part to it. And after this run simply `ng test`.

Comment: I tried that also and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the above described issue with the versions you posted.

With

```
"jsdom": "^16.2.2", 
"karma-jsdom-launcher": "^8.0.2",
"karma": "~4.3.0" 
"karma"-jasmine: "~2.0.1"
```

I got the same error:

```
10% building 4/4 modules 0 active23 04 2020 13:09:45.095:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser jsdom
23 04 2020 13:09:57.422:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9877/
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined]
```

After updating `karma` to `~5.0.0` and `karma-jasmine` to `~3.0.1` the `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined]` error is gone, but the tests are still not started, the console hangs when the Jasmine tests should be started.

In the FAQ of `karma-jsdom-launcher` there is a known issue  [documented here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jsdom-launcher#i-am-using-angular-cli-and-the-test-suite-hangs-indefinitely). It says, that the karma launcher can hang, if the sourcemaps are used. If we try to disable the sourcemaps in the `angular.json` with adding `"sourceMap: false"` this way:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": []
  }
},
```

It really works. I created a demo for this, [it can be checked here](https://github.com/tenkmilan/angular-jsdom-test).

However it is not cool, that the sourcemaps have to be disabled. This means that you won't be able to use the breakpoints in the tests, which can be an inconvenient limitation.

It is worth to consider using Headless Chrome if the limitation with the sourcemaps is painful. A tutorial about using Headless Chrome [can be found here](https://indepth.dev/angular-testing-with-headless-chrome/).

Comment: So I updated karma and karma-jasmine to the versions mentioned and ran it again. This time i got past the origin error but now getting another error. Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)

Comment: Okay, I have found the HTMLCanvasElement issue. It is because of the package web-animations.js in pollyfills.ts. I added the line and installed the package in your project and got the same error. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I took a look at it, but seems to taking too far. Why do you need JSDOM as browser for the tests?

Comment: running it on CI server with no browser. No chrome/headless chrome or phantom js etc. so only choice is jsdom. It works but with web-animations it is throwing error now.

Comment: Any luck on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Nope. I personally would go for installing Chrome on the CI server.